# View Rendering: Is there a better way to control the class name for the view element?

Tags: backbone.js

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: function() {
        return this.model.isNew() ? 'new' : 'old';
    }
```

That's the functionality I would like, but it doesn't work.  I'm not sure when the class name is determined, but the callee is just the element itself; in this case, it would be `<div></div>`.  Is there a way to give className access to the model?

I can, and currently, put another div in my template, in order to control the class, but that div is definitely not needed if I am able to control the class name from the View itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it were me, I'd probably set that type of class within `render()` use a helper function:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        this.applyClass();
        return this;
    },

    applyClass: function() {
        var isNew = this.model.isNew();
        $(this.el)
            .toggleClass('new', isNew)
            .toggleClass('old', !isNew);
    }
});
```

You could then reuse `applyClass` in an event handler later if you need to:

```
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.model.bind('change', this.applyClass, this);
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to use a better name for `applyClass`, too (it's a bit generic). Something that fits your environment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the context of the className function by using _.bindAll in the initialize method

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'className');
  },
  tagName: 'div',
  className: function() {
    return this.model.isNew() ? 'new' : 'old';
  }
});
```

Comment: Cool! What causes this to not work though is that the element has already been created (in `make()`) and the unbound `className` function already called before your `initialize` method is called.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could avoid `className` property and use `attributes` function...

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    attributes: function() {
        return { "class": this.model.isNew() ? 'new' : 'old'
            };
    }
});
```